# c# wpf datagridview selected row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, selecteditem

I got a datagridview with a information of customers. I have background data which I don't represent on datagridview. I try to get customer id on a selected row in datagrid. I try to use this code, but I got an error at converting datagrid.SelectedItem to DataViewRow.

Here is my C# code;

```
private void searchPayment_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)customerDataGrid.SelectedItem;
        String result = (drv["customer_id"]).ToString();
        presenter.getSelecetedCustomerPayment(Convert.ToInt32(result));
    }
```

In debug mode, I can see customerDataGrid.SelectedItem is correct. It returns all my data including "customer_id".

and this is the XAML code for my datagrid;

```
<DataGrid x:Name="customerDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,326,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tc_id_no}" Header="National ID"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding firstname}" Header="Name"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding lastname}" Header="Lastname"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding group_name}" Header="Group"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding birthdate}" Header="Birthdate"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding parent_name}" Header="Parent Name"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding phone_number}" Header="Phone"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding email}" Header="Email"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding gender}" Header="Gender"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SelectedItemProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspxhttp://) returns the (first) currently selected item of your `DataGrid`. This means this is an object of your `Customer` class (thats the name of the class I suppose) and no `DataRowView` or something like that. You can simply get any properties of your `Customer` if you cast the selected item. Note that you have to check if the selected item is null since no selected item is possible:

```
Customer selectedCustomer = customerDataGrid.SelectedItem as Customer;
if (selectedCustomer != null)
{
    //Get the properties you need
    string selectedCustomerId = selectedCustomer.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)DataGrid.SelectedItems[0];

0 is the first item in the first intersection, try getting the index by trial and error method, keep playing with the index until you get the index you want.